# Add menu just in product page

Tags: product

I want to add 2 div just in product page and I add these in `app\design\frontend\default\celebrity\template\page\1column.phtml` but added in all pages and I want to add just in product page, how can I control it?

Comment: Hi Elham, Can you please elaborate your question? at which location do you want to add such div ? Header, footer, content? left column or right column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code in phtml file where you want to add `div`

```
<?php  
$currentUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current' => true));
if (strpos($currentUrl,'catalog/product') == true) { ?>
Add Your div here....
<?php }?>
```